# How do I resolve 'Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity' and 'Unresolved reference: flutter' errors when building a Flutter project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to build my Flutter project in android studio and I get the following errors
`'Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity' 'Unresolved reference: flutter'`
what might be the way to fix these

I tried updating Gradle to the newest version but it is not working